# Can't access constructor with @AllArgsConstructor but works with @RequiredArgsConstructor

Tags: java, lombok

I have a POJO class as follows:

```
@Value
@Builder
public class XYZ {

    @NonNull
    private final String a;

    @NonNull
    private final String b;

    @NonNull
    private final State state;

    public enum State {
        STARTED
    }
}
```

When I try to create the object of XYZ class from my tst/ folder, it fails with an error that constructor cannot be accessed from outside package but when I used @RequiredArgsConstructor in that POJO, then it starts working fine and doesn't show the error. The actual error is this:

> error: XYZ(String,String,State) is not public in XYZ; cannot be
>   accessed from outside package

So, I was wondering what is the difference between @AllArgsConstructor(provided by @Value) and  @RequiredArgsConstructor because of which I am seeing this issue.

Comment: I strongly suspect that your `@Builder` is causing the constructor to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yeah it was due to that. But why is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When processing its annotations, Lombok does not consider the order of those annotations in the source file. Instead, each annotation type has a priority that determines the processing order. This is because there are dependencies between different annotation types.

`@Builder` has a higher priority than `@Value`. So Lombok first generates the package-private all-args constructor required for the builder. As a result, there is already a constructor present when processing `@Value`. According to [the `@Value` documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value), "any explicit constructor, no matter the arguments list, implies lombok will not generate a constructor".

However, in my opinion this is a bit misleading in the documentation. The constructor generated for `@Builder` is more something like an implementation detail, but I would not call it an "explicit constructor". (By "explicit" the authors probably mean "not a default constructor".)

Once you add `@RequiredArgsConstructor` or `@AllArgsConstructor` (which is the same in this case), the constructor becomes public, and neither `@Builder` nor `@Value` has to generate it any more.